# UDP ReadFrom Blocking vs Non Blocking

Tags: sockets, latency

nice to see you guys here : )

I have a latency sensitive trading application which has to receive data from UDP socket. These data are frequent (around 100 per sec) but small (56 bytes).
My current design is to use blocking UDP socket but the speed seems not fast enough. Do you think using spin-loop to do polling and set UDP to be non-blocking; will it be faster ? For CPU-usage, my server is always zero so no need to worry the CPU usage. My current application design is like the following:

### Thread A

Data -> Blocking-UDP-> Push Data in Concurrent Queue (Blocking)

### Thread B

Get Data from Concurrent Queue (Blocking) ----> Processing ---> Send Order in TCP Socket

My measurement on UDP-blocking readfrom latency is around 3us. I think it can be even smaller if using spin-loop + non blocking but I am not sure if there are side effects. I think some experts may suggest a better model an I am willing to listen here.

Another question is you may think the concurrent queue should be the bottle neck as mutex lock and blocking events are involved..... I think of adopting lock-free queue there but no idea about which kind of lock-free queue should be used.

I know some guys may say it has to be measured or profiled in the actual situation but I want to look for some instant advises before taking any action; thanks : ) Highly appreciate if some guys can give some advice on CPU affinity to minimize the latency.

Last, Stackoverflow is the best; I always learn a lot from experts here : )

Comment: Some more information would be useful: how many sockets do you use (or how many different ports need to be monitored)? What platform are you using (.Net? Native? Linux?) When you say "Concurrent queue" do you mean something from some library or your own development?

Comment: Hi Gonzalez; thanks for your reply here : ) 1 port actually as the data has been pre-processed and aggregated by my another data feed engine which receives 8 port data from exchange. My environment is window server with C++ native. I have tired to move the code to Linux but the result is still similar, namely slow. As for the concurrent queue, it is is developed by me using mutex and deque

Comment: I wouldn´t call 3 us slow, exactly, he he. Spin loop + overlapped IO would be probably the fastes way but not sure how much you would save. Curious to see results..